# Package esri is not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular, esri

I'm using `esri` in AngularJs 2 with typescript

```
import esri = require('esri');
import Map = require('esri/map');
import AGSPoint = require("esri/geometry/Point");

import { Component } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app/home/home.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'app/home/home.css' ],
})
export class Home {
  map: Map;

  contructor() {
    this.map = this.createMap();
  }

  private createMap(): Map {
    const point = new Point(-122.45, 37.75); // long, lat
    point.log();

    const mapOptions: esri.MapOptions = {};
    mapOptions.basemap = "topo";
    mapOptions.center = point;
    mapOptions.zoom = 13;

    return new Map("map", mapOptions);
  }
}

class Point extends AGSPoint {

  log() {
    console.log(this.type, this.x, this.y);
  }
}
```

I've installed correctly the typings definitions (`d.ts` files) and they are correctly retrieved.

The index files look like this

```
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">

    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- ArcGIS -->
    <script src="//js.arcgis.com/3.15"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        // defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <app>Loading map...</app>
  </body>

</html>
```

The point is that when I execute the application it doesn't work. The index.html is served by nodejs. it gave me as error

```
localhost:3000/esri/map not found
```

How should I install `esri modules`? how they should be retrieved?

Comment: Where are the scripts located?

Comment: and have you tried: `import esri = require('./esri');`

Comment: I have imported the td.s definition that's all. Esri script aren't there. They should be retrieved somehow but from where?

Comment: https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/typescript here is the example i'm trying to duplicate

Comment: Are they npm modules?

Comment: ^I just checked if it was in the NPM directory and got no luck

Comment: no they aren't npm modules. they are retrieved in some magical way but I don't know how.

Comment: ooh okay, so ESRI uses DOJO to load their resources

Comment: so I should use somehow dojo with sistemjs and look really new for me :-(

Comment: @inoabrian any idea?

Comment: I will try to come up with a solution for you.

Comment: He is using AMD instead of system.
If you want to follow along with his you could do that in your tsconfig.json

Comment: Yes I see. Maybe it is not possible to use systemjs?

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure because Dojo uses amd also.

Comment: The point is that if I remove systemjs is a pain without it. the official tutorial show only this way

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve properly the module we need to map the `esri` to the location of the package using the SystemJS directive `map` doing something like this

```
System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        map: {
          esri: '//js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri'
        },
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
```

now the package are correctly retrieve but still get another error saying the `define` is not function

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the confusingly documented world of 3rd party modules in Angular2 and TypeScript! Here, depending on your setup and environment, are many of the pieces to the puzzle you might need:

//custom_typings.d.ts

```
declare module 'my-module-name' {
  export function foo() : any;
}
```

//app.component.ts

```
import * as MyModule from 'my-module-name';
```

//index.html

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    packages: {
        app: {format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js'},
        "/angular2": {"defaultExtension": false}
    },
    map: {
        'my-module-name': 'node_modules/my-module-name'
    }
});
```

//if you have a registered npm module then you can just cli install it:

```
`npm install my-module-name --save`
```

//Or, if it's not then you can put a custom install binding in `package.json`:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "my-module-name": "git+https://stash.somecompany.com/my-module.name.git#0.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Ok I see and thanks for you explaination. btw everything it clear now we analized the problem and come up with the solution that I need somehow load `esri` using dojo. the point is how use dojo with systemjs?

Comment: Dojo uses AMD modules, and SystemJS can universally load AMD modules.

Comment: that's a nice news but how it is still a mistery for me :-)

Comment: I need to load `esri` using dojo but how systemjs can use dojo. I didn't see any examples

Comment: if we try to follow the example I've posted then I should load dojo using System.import but unfortunately it doesn't work. I get http://localhost:3000/dojo/domReady NOT FOUND. maybe it is some misconfiguration from the server. I mean the index.html is served by a nodejs server and I set in the server the string `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')))` to get static contents

Comment: I really don't understand where the lookup of the package should be made